# [PM2][ERROR] File processes.json not found

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, docker-machine, pm2

I am using a dockerfile to load my node js app,    the image build succeeds for some reason when i run the command `docker run -p 4500:4500 myname/my-docker-image`

I get the response:

```
pm2 launched in no-daemon mode (you can add DEBUG="*" env variable to get more messages)
2016-06-08 06:29:17: [PM2][WORKER] Started with refreshing interval: 30000
2016-06-08 06:29:17: [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
2016-06-08 06:29:17: BUS system [READY] on port /root/.pm2/pub.sock
2016-06-08 06:29:17: RPC interface [READY] on port /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
2016-06-08 06:29:17: [PM2][ERROR] File processes.json not found
2016-06-08 06:29:17: 
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
2016-06-08 06:29:17:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
2016-06-08 06:29:17: --no-daemon option enabled = do not exit pm2 CLI
2016-06-08 06:29:17: PM2 daemon PID = 1
2016-06-08 06:29:17: [PM2] Streaming realtime logs for [all] processes
```

The kicker is the processes.json file clearly being defined in my build for pm2.

Here is the contents of my processes.json file:

```
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "jira-accelo-integration",
            "script": "server.js",
            "merge_logs": true,
            "max_restarts": 20,
            "instances": 4,
            "DEBUG": "*",
            "max_memory_restart": "200M",
            "env": {
                "PORT": 4500,
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And the most important things you should have shown (but didn't) are: 1)path to processes.js 2) how do you pass it to pm2

Comment: path to processes.js?    I can't find anywhere in the documentation for pm2 about processes.js

Comment: Sorry obviously I meant **processes.json**

Comment: 1) my processes.json file lives in my project root and 2) `CMD ["pm2", "start", "processes.json", "--no-daemon"]` is at the end of my dockerfile.

Comment: And in dockerfile you call *pm2 start processes.json*, right?

Comment: not directly - `docker run -p 4500:4500 myname/my-docker-image` -- this is the command that actually calls that process.

Comment: Just a though since i'm not too familiar with docker,  can you run `ls` in dockerfile to make sure the file *processes.json* is listed or `pwd` to make sure you are in the correct directory

Comment: Have you checked that the `processes.json` file is actually being pulled into your Docker image? You can run one-off commands like this to check: `docker run --rm myname/my-docker-image ls /root`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error but the problem in my case turned out to be much simpler, a typo in the file name when creating my processes.json file. These are the steps I took to troubleshoot the problem:

Run the docker container with a shell in interactive mode. Did it start in the right working directory? Are all the files in place, including your processes.json file? Does it work if you execute pm2 start processes.json from in the interactive session?

```
$ docker run -it jla/dockerizing-node-app bash
root@a9ee4c9c7816:/var/www/app/current# pm2 start processes.json --no-daemon
```

Comment out CMD in the Dockerfile and add a new one to verify a command can see your processes.json file.

```
$ edit Dockerfile
CMD ["ls" "-l" "processes.json"]
$ docker build -t jla/dockerizing-node-app .
$ docker run -p 4500:4500 jla/dockerizing-node-app
```

It was at this point, when ls failed, that I noticed my file was named process.json. Maybe the ls command will also fail for you but for other reasons, like not using the right WORKDIR. Try other commands like just ls -l and pwd to see what is going on in your container from the perspective of a command. You should be able to get it to work with some persistence and careful observation.